# Change screen brightness via software end or without drivers?

Tags: windows-7, brightness, display-driver

Is there a software-end hack to let me adjust the brightness of Windows 7 even if the screen driver is malfunctioning? My brightness is all the way up and because I have some critical work files currently here, I don't want to risk making low system-level changes. I want a temporary fix until such time when I can finally get around to doing a full reformat.

Are there any such software which will dim my screen in some way or another?

Comment: Did you try the Windows Mobility Center (`Win+X`) and/or the battery/Power-Options Control Panel applet? You can also try [NirCmd’s](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) `changebrightness` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the default brightness for the current power plan.

Go to -> Control Panel -> Power Options -> Change plan settings.
Check for brightness settings. It should be available for a laptop.

**PS**: I could not give a detailed guide since I am currently using a desktop and I am not able to see the option to dim the display in plan settings.)

Comment: I didn't find any brightness-related settings there though?